# Invalid argument foreach on an Array?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I'm completely lost, I have this code:

```
    $val = explode('?',$_POST['data']);
    print_r($val);
    foreach($val as &$v) {
       //some code
    }
```

and the result is this:

```
Array ( [0] => 1|1|41|1|1|1 [1] => 1|1|31|1|1|1 [2] => 1|1|21|1|1|3 ) 
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in test.php on line 131
```

I really don't get what I'm doing wrong...

**PS** actually I've added `print_r` only to see what was wrong, I don't really need it

Comment: @jhonraymos To make sure the changes are made on the array directly

Comment: @jhonraymos the & is to access the array element by reference, rather than a copy, so it's faster and needed if you want to modify the original array content.

Comment: are you sure that's line 131 and there's not another foreach somewhere throwing the error?

Comment: post the full code.. the error could be in another foreach, make sure the line error corresponds to the posted code..

Comment: @Nelson, using & is not necessarily faster. Since there is this copy-on-write principle in PHP, the only intention of & is to be able to change the element (regarding foreach, at least).

Comment: @OndřejBouda Interesting, didn't know about that, one new thing I learned :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is changing the `$val` somewhere in the foreach.

This code runs fine, see [code path](http://codepad.org/6ZsxuFRi):

```
$_POST['data'] = '1|1|41|1|1|1?1|1|31|1|1|1?1|1|21|1|1|3';

$val = explode( '?', $_POST['data'] );
print_r( $val );
foreach ( $val as &$v ) {
  echo $v;
}
```

Comment: That can't be the reason since `foreach` takes a copy of the array. Just give it a try: `$arr = array(1, 2, 3);
foreach ($arr as $v) {
        echo "$v ";
        $arr = null;
}`

Comment: I have no idea why, but changing the names of the variables to something longer did the job! Thank's!